# Improve my C coding and find issues with code

Tags: c, file, malloc, valgrind

I am new to coding in C and I am trying to figure out the problems my code may have to help me build safer code writing in C. Can anyone tell me what the problem with this code is? I know `malloc` here might fail because of memory leak. However is there any other problem with the code? and what's the best way of initialising `fd`? Please forgive me if this question is not strong enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char *buffer;
    int lent = 0;
    //int i
    read(fd, &lent, sizeof(lent));
    if ((lent + 1) < 0) {
        error("negative length");
        return 0;
    }
    buffer = malloc(lent + 1);
    if (buffer == NULL) { 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    read(fd, buffer, lent);
    buffer[lent] = '\0'; // null terminate buf
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You never set `fd`.

Comment: yes i know fd is not set. i asked whats the best way to set fd. @kaylum i am just trying to figure what possible errors could occur here. i have another code am writing but i need to know if they issues in this that i should avoid that kind of thing

Comment: You initialize it by calling `open()`, what other choice could there be?

Comment: FYI, [codereview.se] is a more appropriate site if you want your code to be reviewed. Stackoverflow is for specific coding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put the issues in comments in the code.

```
int main(){
    char *buffer;
    int lent=0;
    //int i
    read(fd, &lent, sizeof(lent)); // You never declare or set fd -- you need int fd = open("filename", O_RDONLY);
    if ((lent+1) < 0) { // This will allow lent == -1, even though that's negative
        error ("negative length"); // error() is not defined
        return 0;
    }
    buffer = malloc(lent+1);
    if (buffer==NULL) { 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    read(fd,buffer,lent); // depending on what fd refers to, read() might return less than lent bytes, it returns how many bytes it read
    buffer[lent] = '\0'; // null terminate buf
    return 0; 
}
```

You should check the return values from read(), to make sure you didn't get an error or EOF.

Comment: I added the declaration to the comment